# Installing Wordpress in Rails /public - missing mysql extension

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, php, wordpress, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to install Wordpress in my Rails /public folder. I get the following error message:

'Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.'

PHP Version 5.2.4-2ubuntu5 is running.

I assume I need to alter the php.ini file, but I don't know how, or with what.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need to install the mysql extension for PHP. Try `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql` to install it (or install php5-mysql from synaptic). The package manager will modify all files accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. The site is hosted on slicehost - so do I write that in the site management console? or via SSH from my local machine?

Comment: I am not familiar with slicehost, so I can't really comment on that, but if you have SSH access, I would just try this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this: http://forum.slicehost.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=2037